# Implementing 2D Laplacian in Cython for periodic boundary counditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, cython

I have a code that implement a 2D Laplacian for [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) integration method for partial differential equations, using the [roll method of Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) :

```
def lapOp(u):
    """
    This is the laplacian operator on 2D array
    of stencil of 4th accuracy terms
    """
    lap = ((4.0/3.0)*np.roll(u,1,axis=0) + (4.0/3.0)*np.roll(u,-1,axis=0) + (4.0/3.0)*np.roll(u,1,axis=1) + (4.0/3.0)*np.roll(u,-1,axis=1) -5.0*u)
    lap -= ((1.0/12.0)*np.roll(u,2,axis=0) + (1.0/12.0)*np.roll(u,-2,axis=0) + (1.0/12.0)*np.roll(u,2,axis=1) + (1.0/12.0)*np.roll(u,-2,axis=1))
    lap = lap / hh
    return lap
```

I would like to cythonize my code - will the roll method work in my pyx code or should I implement the roll method using C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: `roll` will work in Cython, but it won't be much (any?) faster.

If you want speed you should probably avoiding using something like `roll` altogether (it's slow because it creates a complete copy each time it's called) and instead use indexing to get views of large chunks of the numpy array `u`. You shouldn't need Cython and probably won't benefit from it.

An incomplete example is below (which shows enough to give the gist):

```
def lapOp(u):
    lap = np.empty_like(u)
    # this bit is equivalent to (4.0/3)*np.roll(u,1,axis=0)
    lap[1:,:] = (4.0/3.0)*u[:-1,:]
    lap[0,:] = (4.0/3.0)*u[-1,:]

    # add (4.0/3)*np.roll(u,-1,axis=0)
    lap[:-1,:] += (4.0/3.0)*u[1:,:]
    lap[-1,:] += (4.0/3.0)*u[0,:]

    # add (4.0/3)*np.roll(u,1,axis=1)
    lap[:,1:] += (4.0/3.0)*u[:,:-1]
    lap[:,0] += (4.0/3.0)*u[:,-1]

    # the remainder is left as a rather tedious exercise for the reader

    return lap/hh
```